# ls /vagrant inside a (virtual box) VM hangs

Tags: vagrant

I provision a VM (vagrant up) with the Vagrant file below,
I then "vagrant ssh " into it,
then **ls /vagrant **

and it hangs for ever, I appended an strace below.

The link to the virtual box is not stable, so I copied it here :

https://bitbucket.org/genap/public_files/downloads/saucy-server-cloudimg-amd64-vagrant-disk1.box

The hang occurs with this version as well...

Vagrant version 1.4.3
Host OS version :

```
  Distributor ID:   Ubuntu
  Description:  Ubuntu 13.04
  Release:  13.04
  Codename: raring
```

The Vagrantfile :

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "UbuntuServer13.04"
  config.vm.box_url = "http://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/vagrant/saucy/current/saucy-server-cloudimg-amd64-vagrant-disk1.box"
  config.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.78.9"
  config.vm.host_name = "genap-portal-dev"
  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
    vb.name = "genap-portal-dev-test"
    vb.memory = 1024
  end
  if Vagrant.has_plugin?("vagrant-hostmanager")
    config.hostmanager.enabled = true
    config.hostmanager.manage_host = true
  end
end


execve("/bin/ls", ["ls", "/vagrant/"], [/* 22 vars */]) = 0
brk(0)                                  = 0x22ab000
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f2cb4bca000
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=25505, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 25505, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7f2cb4bc3000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libselinux.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\240Z\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=134224, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 2234088, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f2cb4788000
mprotect(0x7f2cb47a7000, 2097152, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f2cb49a7000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1f000) = 0x7f2cb49a7000
mmap(0x7f2cb49a9000, 1768, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f2cb49a9000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\0#\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=31760, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 2128984, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f2cb4580000
mprotect(0x7f2cb4587000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f2cb4786000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x6000) = 0x7f2cb4786000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libacl.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0`\34\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=31168, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f2cb4bc2000
mmap(NULL, 2126336, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f2cb4378000
mprotect(0x7f2cb437f000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f2cb457e000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x6000) = 0x7f2cb457e000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\360\36\2\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=1853400, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 3961912, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f2cb3fb0000
mprotect(0x7f2cb416d000, 2097152, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f2cb436d000, 24576, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1bd000) = 0x7f2cb436d000
mmap(0x7f2cb4373000, 17464, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f2cb4373000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\220\31\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=256224, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 2351392, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f2cb3d71000
mprotect(0x7f2cb3dae000, 2097152, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f2cb3fae000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x3d000) = 0x7f2cb3fae000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\360l\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=135757, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f2cb4bc1000
mmap(NULL, 2212936, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f2cb3b54000
mprotect(0x7f2cb3b6b000, 2097152, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f2cb3d6b000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x17000) = 0x7f2cb3d6b000
mmap(0x7f2cb3d6d000, 13384, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f2cb3d6d000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\320\16\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=14664, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 2109736, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f2cb3950000
mprotect(0x7f2cb3953000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f2cb3b52000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x2000) = 0x7f2cb3b52000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libattr.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\340\20\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=18624, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 2113760, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f2cb374b000
mprotect(0x7f2cb374f000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f2cb394e000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x3000) = 0x7f2cb394e000
close(3)                                = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f2cb4bc0000
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f2cb4bbf000
mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f2cb4bbd000
arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x7f2cb4bbd800) = 0
mprotect(0x7f2cb436d000, 16384, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f2cb394e000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f2cb3b52000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f2cb3d6b000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f2cb3fae000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f2cb457e000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f2cb4786000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f2cb49a7000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x619000, 4096, PROT_READ)     = 0
mprotect(0x7f2cb4bcc000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
munmap(0x7f2cb4bc3000, 25505)           = 0
set_tid_address(0x7f2cb4bbdad0)         = 2285
set_robust_list(0x7f2cb4bbdae0, 24)     = 0
futex(0x7fff2e8a5dfc, FUTEX_WAIT_BITSET_PRIVATE|FUTEX_CLOCK_REALTIME, 1, NULL, 7f2cb4bbd800) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
rt_sigaction(SIGRTMIN, {0x7f2cb3b5a7e0, [], SA_RESTORER|SA_SIGINFO, 0x7f2cb3b63bb0}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGRT_1, {0x7f2cb3b5a860, [], SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO, 0x7f2cb3b63bb0}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, [RTMIN RT_1], NULL, 8) = 0
getrlimit(RLIMIT_STACK, {rlim_cur=8192*1024, rlim_max=RLIM64_INFINITY}) = 0
statfs("/sys/fs/selinux", 0x7fff2e8a5df0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
statfs("/selinux", 0x7fff2e8a5df0)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
brk(0)                                  = 0x22ab000
brk(0x22cc000)                          = 0x22cc000
open("/proc/filesystems", O_RDONLY)     = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0444, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f2cb4bc9000
read(3, "nodev\tsysfs\nnodev\trootfs\nnodev\tb"..., 1024) = 372
read(3, "", 1024)                       = 0
close(3)                                = 0
munmap(0x7f2cb4bc9000, 4096)            = 0
open("/usr/lib/locale/locale-archive", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=1607664, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 1607664, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7f2cb4a34000
close(3)                                = 0
ioctl(1, SNDCTL_TMR_TIMEBASE or SNDRV_TIMER_IOCTL_NEXT_DEVICE or TCGETS, {B38400 opost isig icanon echo ...}) = 0
ioctl(1, TIOCGWINSZ, {ws_row=31, ws_col=113, ws_xpixel=0, ws_ypixel=0}) = 0
stat("/vagrant/", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0775, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/vagrant/", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_DIRECTORY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
getdents(3, /* 1 entries */, 32768)     = 32
getdents(3, /* 1 entries */, 32768)     = 32
getdents(3, /* 1 entries */, 32768)     = 32
getdents(3, /* 1 entries */, 32768)     = 32
...
...
```

The last line (getdents(3, /* 1 entries */, 32768)     = 32)
is then repeated infinitely

Answer (score 2):

Almost always the problems with vboxsf mounts are caused by buggy or mismatching VirtualBox Guest Additions on the guest. At least the major and minor versions numbers must match the VirtualBox version on the host.

The options are:

- Use the [vagrant-vbguest](https://github.com/dotless-de/vagrant-vbguest) plugin to upgrade the guest additions automatically when needed. Handy, but slows down creation of new VM instances if it needs to reinstall the additions.
- Find a box with up-to-date guest additions. And think if you can trust the provider of the box image.
- Build your own boxes with matching guest additions version. See [packer.io](http://www.packer.io) and [bento templates](https://github.com/opscode/bento) for example.
- Upgrade the guest additions on a VM manually, and [`vagrant package`](https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/cli/package) and `add` it as a new base box.